# Creating react native app custom background behind image or border

Tags: javascript, android, ios, css, react-native

I need help with icons for my app. I keep getting gray borders around the characters and I want to insert a custom background behind each character. I'm just lost. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the code from the React native project.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, ImageBackground, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component() {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row' }}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}>
          <Image source={{ uri: 'http://www.pngmart.com/files/2/Spider-Man-Transparent-Background.png' }}
            style={{ width: 122, height: 550 }} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}>
          <Image source={{
            uri:
              'https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/avengers-assemble/images/d/d6/Usa_avengers_skchi_blackwidow_n_6e8100ad.png/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/449?cb=20170426073401'
          }}
            style={{ width: 122, height: 550 }} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}>
          <Image source={{ uri: 'https://clipart.info/images/ccovers/1516942387Hulk-Png-Cartoon.png' }}
            style={{ width: 122, height: 500 }} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <ImageBackground source={{ uri: 'http://www.color-hex.com/palettes/6563.png' }} style={{ width: '100', height: '100' }}>
          <Text>Inside</Text>
        </ImageBackground>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
///need help with coloring each icon
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
    alignItems: 'bottom',
    justifyContent: 'bottom',
  },
  button: {
    backgroundColor: '#859a9b',
    borderRadius: 150,
    padding: 1,
    marginBottom: -100,
    shadowColor: 'white',
    shadowOffset: { width: 10, height: 0 },
    shadowRadius: 20,
    shadowOpacity: 0.45,
  },
});
```

Comment: Question title is very impressive.

Comment: Is this code working properly without any errors ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all please provide correct working code in stackoverflow. 
There are some errors in your code here.

**Errors**

1. Invalid prop in **alignItems** style in your code. There is no prop called **bottom**. It needs to be **`alignItems:'flex-end'`**
2. Invalid prop in **justifyContent** in your code. That should be **`justifyContent: 'flex-end'`** . [More about layout props](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layout-props#alignitems)

To avoid gray border around characters firstly you need to get your device width and height.

```
import {Dimensions} from 'react-native'
```

Then after that create const for get device width and height before your main class.

```
const width = Dimensions.get('window').width; 
const height = Dimensions.get('window').height;
```

You need to add background image code like this..

```
  <ImageBackground source={{uri: 'http://www.color-hex.com/palettes/6563.png'}}
    style={{width: width, height: height,flexDirection:'row'}}>
    </ImageBackground>
```

Remove the button background color code  `backgroundColor: '#859a9b',` 
The full correct code should look like this...

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image,ImageBackground,button,  
TouchableOpacity,Dimensions} from 'react-native';

const width = Dimensions.get('window').width;
const height = Dimensions.get('window').height;


export default class App extends Component<{}> {
  render() {
   return (
 <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
 <ImageBackground source={{uri: 'http://www.color-hex.com/palettes/6563.png'}} style={{width: width, height: height,flexDirection:'row'}}>

    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}>
      <Image source={{uri: 'http://www.pngmart.com/files/2/Spider-Man-Transparent-Background.png'}}
   style={{width: 122, height: 550}} />
    </TouchableOpacity>
    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}>
      <Image source={{uri:
      'https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/avengers-assemble/images/d/d6/Usa_avengers_skchi_blackwidow_n_6e8100ad.png/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/449?cb=20170426073401'}}
   style={{width: 122, height: 550}} />
    </TouchableOpacity>
    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}>
      <Image source={{uri: 'https://clipart.info/images/ccovers/1516942387Hulk-Png-Cartoon.png'}}
   style={{width: 122, height: 500}} />
    </TouchableOpacity>


  </ImageBackground>
    </View>
  );
 }
}
///need help with coloring each icon
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
flex: 1,
backgroundColor: 'blue',
alignItems: 'flex-end',
justifyContent: 'flex-end',
  },
  button: {
borderRadius: 150,
padding: 1,
marginBottom: -100,
shadowColor: 'white',
shadowOffset: { width: 10, height: 0 },
shadowRadius: 20,
shadowOpacity: 0.45,
  },
});
```

[image]

Comment: but the grey boarders around the characters are still there how should i get rid of them?

Comment: @MarloJones you mean the background color of the characters ??

Comment: @MarloJones Just remove this line **backgroundColor: '#859a9b'** from your button style. It should work now

Comment: @MarloJones if your problem is solved give thumbs up for this answer :)